# How to override the slug of ultimate member profile page?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, permalinks, slug, ultimate-member

I want to change the default firstname-lastname slug to something different, like firstname-lastname-city-category. How exactly can I do this using ultimate members plugin ? I am using free version. I could not find any filter for this so far ? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so if anyone coming here facing the same problem, here is the answer. Ultimate Member plugin does not provide any way to override the slug of the profile page, I have contacted them and they said it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I just create a pull request to add this feature

https://github.com/ultimatemember/ultimatemember/pull/1004

if you don't want to wait for the PR you can look into the code to implement on your local version in the meanwhile

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).